# Update to the database didn't work

Tags: c#, winforms, ms-access-2010

I got the problem. I want to update the data to the database, but the database won't update.

Here is the code:

**Updated** Below Code:

```
else if (firstForm.textBox1.Text == "Seranne")
            {
                string query = "SELECT [Quantity], [Description], [Price] FROM [Seranne] WHERE [Code] IN (";

                OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection(connectionString);

                conn.Open();

                if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[0].Text, out codeValue))
                {
                    query = query + codeValue.ToString();
                }

                for (int i = 1; i < 17; i++)
                {
                    if (int.TryParse(this.textBoxCodeContainer[i].Text, out codeValue))
                    {
                        query = query + "," + codeValue.ToString();
                    }
                }

                query = query + ")";

                OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(query, conn);

                cmd.Parameters.Add("Code", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);
                cmd.Parameters.Add("Quantity", System.Data.OleDb.OleDbType.Integer);

                OleDbDataReader dReader;

                dReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                while (dReader.Read())
                {
                    if (textBoxCodeContainer[index].TextLength != 0)
                    {
                        this.textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Maximum = Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString());
                        this.textBoxDescContainer[index].Text = dReader["Description"].ToString();
                        this.textBoxSubTotalContainer[index].Text = dReader["Price"].ToString();
                    }

                    if (textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value != 0 && textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value >= Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString()))
                    {
                        newVal = textBoxQuantityContainer[index].Value - Convert.ToDecimal(dReader["Quantity"].ToString());
                        cmd = new OleDbCommand("UPDATE [Seranne] SET [Quantity] ='" + newVal + "' WHERE [Code] IN ('");
                    }

                    index += 1;
                }

                conn.Close();
                dReader.Close();
            }
        }

        private void UpdateQuantity()
        {
            System.Media.SoundPlayer sound = new System.Media.SoundPlayer(@"C:\Windows\Media\Windows Notify.wav");
            sound.Play();
            MessageBox.Show("Updated Successfully", "Success");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            UpdateQuantity();
        }
```

Above code all worked, excepts for updating the `Quantity` to the database. What I mean is, I set the `Quantity` in database to 100, when I set `Quantity` to `10` in my program and update it, the database should be update the `Quantity` to `90` (because 100 - 10), but it is still at `100`.

Could I wrong somewhere?

Here is the link of the screenshots:
(ScreenShot 1)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rph5iuh371rc9ny/Untitled.png

(ScreenShot 2)
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5q8pyztqy7ejupy/Capture.PNG

In the Screenshot 1, I already set the quantity to `10` and the messagebox show that the data has been updated successfully and the data in the database supposed to be 90 (because 100-10). But, in the Screenshot 2 where the database is, the `Quantity` still at `100`.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I edited your post about 20 min ago. Because you made edits to your post without refreshing your screen, you lost most of my changes (like the screenshots I put in for you).

Comment: @gunr2171: i am sorry for that. Could you please re-post the screenshots that you edit in my question? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `OleDbCommand` but you are not executing the query against the database.

You need to open the `OleDbConnection` which you have not included in your code (if it even exists).  It should look something like:

```
connection.Open();
```

Where `connection` is an `OleDbConnection` object.

Also your query does not look complete.

```
 UPDATE [Seranne] SET [Quantity] ='" + newVal + "' WHERE [Code] IN ("
```

Is not valid `SQL`.

The `UPDATE` statement should look something like:

```
UPDATE [Table] SET Quantity = newVal WHERE Code IN (Val1, Val2, Val3)
```

You will also want to change that to use `SQL paramerterized queries` to prevent `SQL Injection`.

Comment: I think the OP wants to update all the rows which have `CODE` being empty or NULL. He used `IN('')` to achieve that but as you said it's not a valid SQL. You should turn that idea into code.

Comment: @KingKing - the statement reads `IN (` not `IN ('')` ... so I believe the query is incorrect. The OP needs to clarify a lot more IMO.

Comment: maybe he mistyped it, you're right, it's a double quote not 2 single quotes. If so, the correct query is exactly `IN ('')`.

Comment: @DarrenDavies: i already edited the code, please refer to the question again. Thanks.